# Script throws confirmation window which not needed. How to delete?

Tags: javascript

Good day developers. I have script right here: [http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/x4XQp/10/].
This script always throws confirmation window, it every time pop up on the middle of the screen when I select something. How to prevent window to pop up???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove it from your code:

```
alert(this.value)
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. I'm sorry for this stupid question, I'm new in javascript and not know what to do. Hey can I add placeholder to this script to put example inside to this script??

Answer (score 2):

Remove the alert...

```
    alert(this.value)
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. I'm sorry for this stupid question, I'm new in javascript and not know what to do. Hey can I add placeholder to this script to put example inside to this script??